# Filter Postfix email account with CatchAll

Tags: linux, email, debian, postfix-mta

my boss told me to do this weird think for our client (forgive my english):
On our server with old ISPconfig (propably first version) we have an email for one site called info@domain.com and it's set up to catch all emails to this domain. Our client downloads all emails from there and then sorts them by email name. They only have like three email adresses that they want (for example: desk@domain.com, boss@domain.com, assistant@domain.com). However among emails to these mentioned adresses there are thousands of spam emails sent to whatever@domain.com and our client doesn't want to download these.

My question is: How can I setup postfix for a info@domain.com with CatchAll to keep only emails sent to these three mentioned adresses and delete the others?

P.S.
I don't need another and smarter workaround because our client wants his emails handled exactly this way

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want are aliases, not a catch-all - i.e. remove the catch-all from info@domain.com, then make desk@domain.com, boss@domain.com, assistant@domain.com aliases of info@domiain.com.  This will make is so that mail sent to any one of these four addresses will be routed to the mailbox for info@domain.com, and mail sent to any_other_address@domain.com would be undeliverable.  See http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html.